# Can I use fitted ML model as a part of a function in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, anaconda

Can I minimize this function using scipy.optimize?

```
def obj(x):
    Budget = ((df['CPP TA 30'] / 30 * df['TVC']) * x).sum()
    x = (x - min_train_x) / (max_train_x-min_train_x)
    x = np.array([x])
    return (0.05 * model.predict(x) - (1.7 * (Budget / 10**10)))[0][0]
x0 = np.random.uniform(size = 23) 
x0 = (x0 / np.sum(x0)) * 1800
from scipy.optimize import minimize
res = minimize(obj, x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can. Why not try?

If your model is smooth (e.g. linear or neural network), optimization will converge nicely. The only problem is that with nonlinear models there might be multiple local optima, so it would be safe to try different starting points or initialize with some heuristic.

If the model is not smooth (e.g. ensembles of trees) there might be problems with convergence, and you should use a gradient-free algorithm like Nelder-Mead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is indeed a neural network model. The problem I have is that minimization returns x0 that I passed to it in the first place. x0 is randomly initialized so the problem must be something else.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal working example? I write code like in the description and optimized x is the same as x0.

Comment: Minimal working example is a code I could run on my machine and get the same results as you.